# Lots of Bluescreens on Custom Built Computer (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, bsod

First of all, I'm really frustrated...
I just installed Windows 10 on a 200GB partition on my 1TB Samsung 850 EVO SSD.
Unfortunately, I'm getting tons of bluescreens and I don't really know why (especially ntoskrnl.exe). You can download the dump files [here](https://mega.nz/#!FAtzGSrL!yS6FJYThVw2O3I8_npYW9HvnxLgGj8Qj4LQ9AJRnUbo). I already fixed the LGBusEnum.sys bluescreens by disabling the *Logitech Gaming Virtual Bus Enumerator* under *System Devices* in the Device Manager.

I ran a memory check (Ubuntu installer and Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool) > no errors.
I ran chkdsk on my C: drive and on my D: drive (software and data) > no errors.
And I think, all the drivers **should** be installed. At least I installed my graphics card driver and all the drivers which came with my mainboard.

I don't have these problems on Windows 7, which is installed on another SSD.

**Computer Specs**
Mainboard: *Intel DZ87KLT75K*
CPU: *Intel Core i7-4771 3.50GHz, 4 Cores, 8 Logical Processors*
CPU Cooler: *be quiet! Dark Rock 3*
Installed Physical Memory: *16GB (2x8GB Kingston HyperX FURY DDR3, 1600MHz)*
Graphics Card: *MSI NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970*
SSDs: *Samsung 850 EVO, 120GB Basic* and *Samsung 850 EVO, 1TB Pro*
HDD: *HD WD Red Pro 3TB SATA-III*
Power Adapter: *be quiet! Pure Power L8-CM 630W*
I also got an Elgato Game Capture HD60 Pro installed in my computer. I downloaded and installed the software and the driver belonging to this device from the official Elgato website.

Do you have any ideas, where these problems could come from and how I can fix them?

I appreciate every helpful answer ***so*** much! Thanks!
Martin

Comment: IME, varying BSoD sources that change "randomly" are almost always RAM.

Unless you're doing repetitive memory tests for 72 hours+ straight using a decent program like Memtest86+, you're not really testing the RAM (IMO anyway).

Also IME, Kinston HyperX RAM is finicky as heck about timings (even in paired sets). So bad that I'd personally choose Kingston Value RAM long before I tried another pair of HyperX..

Start by trying one RAM stick at a time and/or different, known-good RAM.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 So... I removed one RAM stick, running with 8GB of RAM now. No bluescreen for a long time now. Do I have to assume that the removed RAM stick is broken?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I went to bed about 1am and left my computer running; just to see if he makes it through the night without me doing anything. The only ooened application was Steam. As I got up at 6am. I went to my pc and saw another bluescreen in bmuescreenview; tcpip.sys - DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL at about 3:30am. Computer was running with one RAM stick.

Comment: share CPU-Z pictures of memory and SPD tabs: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here you go (http://imgur.com/a/UAJBJ). Slot #1, #2 and #3 are empty in the SPD tab. *Edit: Also added a screenshot of some new bluescreens...*

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution (after 5 days)...

Thanks to Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I decided to remove one of my RAM sticks and it seemed to work for a bit. I had some bluescreens later on again... so I decided to reinstall Windows 10 with one RAM stick present.

The result of this: proper working Windows 10.

The broken RAM stick must have been messing up the whole installation there...

Thanks anyway to the two who took their time to write a comment :)

Comment: ok, but also the Command Rate of 1 could be the issue of crashes. A more stable value would be a CR value of 2.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Unfortunately, it is still not fixed 100%... :/ Having some issues with *ntoskrnl.exe*. Screenshot of the dump files in bluescreenview: http://imgur.com/a/So2Wr

Comment: try to change the Command Rate value to 2.

Comment: is the PC stable with Command Rate of 2?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I went back to Windows 7, but I will try the command rate change later. TBH I don't even know how to change this at the moment...

Comment: look in BIOS/UEFI in the advanced options. first run CPU-Z and look if the timings are ok when you compare the memory and SPD tab